# Strange behaviour of passing out refernce in binding of lambda function

Tags: c++11, bind, lambda

I want to pass out some parameter from the lambda function, so I bind a reference parameter to a lambda function. However, the outer variable is not changed after calling the function. If I bind the lambda function with the pointer of outer variable, the result is correct.

I show the test program as follows and want to know why the outer variable does not change, given that I have already defined the pass-by-reference lambda function `[&]`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string acc_ref, acc_ptr;
    //  define function via reference
    auto fProcRefEx = [&](string& acc, const string& s) -> void
    {
        acc += s;
    };
    auto fProcRef = bind(fProcRefEx, acc_ref, placeholders::_1);
    //  define function via pointer
    auto fProcPtrEx = [&](string* pacc, const string& s) -> void
    {
        (*pacc) += s;
    };
    auto fProcPtr = bind(fProcPtrEx, &acc_ptr, placeholders::_1);
    //  test
    vector<string> v = {"abc", "def"};
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), fProcRef);
    cout << "acc_ref: " << acc_ref << endl;  //  acc_ref is empty, wrong
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), fProcPtr);
    cout << "acc_ptr: " << acc_ptr << endl;  //  acc_ptr is "abcdef", correct
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `for( auto&& str:v ) { fProcRef(str); }` is as efficient as, and often more clear than, `std::foreach(v.begin(),v.end(),fProcRef);` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `std::bind` will decay the reference to just a plain value type when it stores `acc_ref`.  ie In the unspecified object instance returned from bind, it will have a member `string acc_ref`, not `string& acc_ref`.  You have to use `std::ref` to make it really store a reference:

```
auto fProcRef = bind(fProcRefEx, ref(acc_ref), placeholders::_1);
```